# Correct way to catch a specific exception when wrapped in a PSInvalidCastException

Tags: powershell, exception, powershell-5.0

Given the following invalid XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root><nodeNotClosed></root>
```

This PowerShell will capture the invalid cast exception:

```
$path = 'c:\temp\invalidXml.xml'
try {
    $myXml = [xml](Get-Content -Path $path -Raw)
} catch [System.Management.Automation.PSInvalidCastException] {
    "'$path' is not a valid XML document"
}
```

However, I only want the catch block to catch issues related to casting the file's content to XML; not other types of cast exception.  That could be done like this:

```
$path = 'c:\temp\invalidXml.xml'
try {
    $myXml = [xml](Get-Content -Path $path -Raw)
    #some other code which may cause a PSInvalidCastException to be thrown. e.g.
    #$myDate = [DateTime]'not a date'
} catch [System.Management.Automation.PSInvalidCastException] {
    if ($_.Exception.InnerException -as [System.Xml.XmlException]) {
        "'$path' is not a valid XML document"
    } else {
        throw #not the exception we wanted to catch, so throw it back
    }
}
```

However, that feels messy.  Is there a better way?  E.g. Something like the below (I've tried this but it doesn't work; as here we're trying to catch the inner exception rather than the real exception).

```
$path = 'c:\temp\invalidXml.xml'
try {
    $myXml = [xml](Get-Content -Path $path -Raw)
} catch [System.Xml.XmlException] {
    "'$path' is not a valid XML document"
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately not.  The `try/catch` mechanism doesn't look at the `InnerException` to my knowledge.